# libav (avconv) thumbnail from video hosted on s3

Tags: video, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, wowza, libav

I am using an Ubuntu Amazon EC2 instance with libav tools installed. I am storing videos (mp4's) on Amazon's s3.

Taking a thumbnail from a video works, however, if I am taking a single frame thumbnail from 50 minutes into the video - it takes forever (4 minutes +) to extract that single frame. If I take the thumbnail from the first minute or so of the video, it works almost flawlessly.

I tried feeding avconv a RTMP stream (using our Wowza RTMP out/and also tried Cloudcast) instead of just specifying where the video is via http on Amazons s3. I figured this would improve my results as the file would be streamed. No improvements.

I've also tried accessing the file via mounting the bucket (s3fs) on the EC2 instance: no improvement.

My avconv shell looks like this: 
`avconv -i 'rtmp://s31pf2e6zgypct.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/1001/Conservation31814_850.mp4' -ss 00:10:00 -vsync 1 -qscale 1 -vframes 1 /snaps/1551.png`

Any recommendations? I would greatly appreciate the community's advice.